# How to access json data in django?

Tags: json, django

I want to access **session_key** from JSON response. In login api I am sending credential it response back with `Content-Type: application/json` I need to access session_key. How to access session_key for json response.

```
credential["username"]="john"
credential["password"]="xxx"
response =c.put('/api/login', data=json.dumps(credential))
```

**JSON Respone**

```
  print response.content
```

**output**

```
{"message": "", "result": {"username": "john", "session_key": "xyx"}}
```

When I tried to use print(response.content.result) getting error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'result'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `response.content` is json you just have to decode it to a python dict.

```
import json

content = json.loads(response.content)
key = content['result']['session_key']
```

Answer (score 2):

In request.content you have json data.. you have to get that data to python dict..

You can try this:

```
json.loads(response.content)['result']['session_key']
```

or if you use requests:

```
response.content.json()['result']['session_key']
```